# UIView transitionWithView with UILabel loses rounded corners during transition

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

I currently have a `UIView` that has `UILabel`s sitting on top of it.

These `UILabel`s have rounded corners.

I have a button which I press, which then programmatically removes all these labels, using the `UIView` `transitionWithView` method.

However, during the transition, the rounded corners are lost.

Is it possible to maintain these rounded corners during the transition?
i.e. The corners should remain rounded BEFORE, DURING and AFTER the transition.

Here's some example code:

```
@interface ExampleViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *view;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *myLabel;

@end

@implementation ExampleViewController

- (void) viewDidLOad
{
   self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];      
   [self.myLabel setText:@"Example Label"];
   [self.myLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(100,100)];     // position the label somewhere on the screen
   [self.myLabel.layer setCornerRadius:5];       // set the corner radius
   [self.myLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];   // found this particular line on another stackoverflow thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604215/uiview-transitionwithview-discarding-layer-settings)
   [self.myLabel setHidden:NO];
   [self.myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
   [self.myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

   [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
   [self.view addSubview:self.myLabel];
}

// user interaction
- (IBAction)labelOff:(id)sender 
{
   BOOL hidden = [self.myLabel isHidden];
   [UIView transitionWithView:self.myLabel 
                     duration:1
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                   animations:NULL
                   completion:NULL];

   [self.myLabel setHidden:!hidden];
}

@end
```

I am using **XCode 5** and **iOS 7**. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean **maintain these rounded corners during the transition?**

Comment: Sorry - forgot to add in backgorund colour and sizetoFit. Edited.

So, when the label is first displayed, the label has rounded corners. When i transition the label to hide it, the corners become "not rounded", as it were.

Comment: My Que is : you want the Rounded corners after the Transition Or just want while transition..?

Comment: Ah ok - i want the rounded corners BEFORE the transition, DURING, and AFTER the transition (although afterward the labels will be hidden anyway - but i want to then bring the labels back).

When i do transition from hidden to non-hidden, the labels do actually retain their rounded corners DURING. It's just the transition from non-hidden to hidden where the rounded corners seem to be lost.

Comment: Here is the actual answer that uses `transitionWithView:` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604215/uiview-transitionwithview-discarding-layer-settings. Just set the `masksToBounds` property of the view's layer to `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about how the corner radius is getting removed during transition. But here is an alternative method you can use which has the same end result.

```
- (IBAction)labelOff:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^{
                         self.myLabel.alpha = !self.myLabel.alpha;
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that, you need to empty the UILabel.text but the properties should be avail. right?, Then

```
BOOL hidden; // Declare under @interface

- (IBAction)labelOff:(id)sender 
{
   if(hidden){
      hidden =false;
      [self.myLabel setText:@""];
   }
   else{
      hidden =true;
     [self.myLabel setText:@"Example Label"];
   }
   [UIView transitionWithView:self.myLabel 
                     duration:1
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                   animations:NULL
                   completion:NULL];


}
```

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately got the same result.